# How do I use a Twig template to generate Email content from inside a plugin I'm making?

Tags: plugin-development, emails

I'm trying to do a nicely formatted email from a plugin I'm making. The standard way I've been doing simple emails is all entirely in the code, somewhat like this:

```
$notificationEmail = new EmailModel();
$notificationEmail -> toEmail  = $userEmail;
$notificationEmail -> subject  = "Subject here";
$notificationEmail -> body     = "Thanks $userName, you’re now registered on our website.";
$notificationEmail -> htmlBody = " ... MASSIVE COMPLICATED STUFF THATS FAR BETTER SUITED TO TWIG ... "
craft()->email->sendEmail($notificationEmail);
```

I've now got an email that is far better suited to being generated via a Twig template because I'm going to have to loop through relational fields and all sorts. I have no idea how and I don't seem to know what to Google to get what I'm after... Anyone got pointers to this sort of thing?

Comment: Guessing either `$notificationEmail->htmlBody = craft()->templates->renderString($myComplicatedStuff);` or `$notificationEmail->htmlBody = craft()->templates->renderTemplate('/path/to/my/complicated/template');` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Quite possibly the latter! How do I pass the User or other variables to that template though?

Comment: Actually it's just `render()` for the latter and takes a 2nd $variables param. https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#render-detail

Comment: Let me now if that works for you and I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brad for providing the bulk of the answer. In more detail the line needing to be changed was this:

```
$notificationEmail -> htmlBody = craft()->templates->render('PLUGIN-FOLDER-NAME/TEMPLATE-NAME', ['theUser' => $user]);
```

I could then use {{ theUser }} (Which is a UserModel) in the TEMPLATE-NAME template to generate everything I needed.

So the full solution, to send an Email from a plugin, but using a Twig template to generate the HTML email content was:

```
$myEmail             = new EmailModel();
$myEmail -> toEmail  = $user->email;
$myEmail -> subject  = "Subject here";
$myEmail -> body     = "PLAIN TEXT CONTENT";
$myEmail -> htmlBody = craft()->templates->render('PLUGIN-FOLDER-NAME/TEMPLATE-NAME', ['theUser' => $user]);
craft()->email->sendEmail($myEmail);
```

Where $user was a variable containing a UserModel which I'd already got from previous code in the plugin I was writing.

https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#render-detail for more detail (but for which I wish there were example code of how to use, and not just a dictionary).